# Starting a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm relatively new to programming in general so be gentle =| I'm trying to start a new activity from a basic one that displays a couple of text inputs, a checkbox, and a button. When the button is pressed I want it to switch to the new activity. The code compiles but when I press the button in Android it simply crashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the code sample:**

```
public class Something extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.login);

       Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
       login.setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {

       startActivity(new Intent().setClass(Something.this, That.class));
   }
}
```

**Error Log:**

> I/ActivityManager(  240): Starting activity: Intent {
>   cmp=jano.huerta.sfgc/.HOME  } D/AndroidRuntime(13612): Shutting down
>   VM W/dalvikvm(13612): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught
>   exception (group=0x4 0025a08) E/AndroidRuntime(13612): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(13612): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity Co
>   mponentInfo{jano.huerta.sfgc/jano.huerta.sfgc.HOME}:
>   android.content.ActivityNot FoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {jano.huerta.sfgc/jano.hu erta.sfgc.SUMMARY}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
>   ity(ActivityThread.java:2787) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivi
>   ty(ActivityThread.java:2803) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(Activi tyThread.java:135)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac tivityThread.java:2136)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja va:99)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea d.java:4937)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5 21)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
>   rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot eInit.java:626)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(13612): Caused by:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: U nable to find explicit
>   activity class {jano.huerta.sfgc/jano.huerta.sfgc.SUMMARY }; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivit
>   yResult(Instrumentation.java:1563) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.resolveActivityInf
>   o(ActivityThread.java:2597) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivit
>   y(LocalActivityManager.java:277) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.
>   getContentView(TabHost.java:651) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost. java:323)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:21 3)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   jano.huerta.sfgc.HOME.onCreate(HOME.java:23) E/AndroidRuntime(13612): 
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCre
>   ate(Instrumentation.java:1069) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
>   ity(ActivityThread.java:2751) E/AndroidRuntime(13612):        ... 11
>   more W/ActivityManager(  240):   Force finishing activity
>   jano.huerta.sfgc/.HOME W/ActivityManager(  240):   Force finishing
>   activity jano.huerta.sfgc/.SFGC W/ActivityManager(  240): Activity
>   pause timeout for HistoryRecord{466bbec0 jano .huerta.sfgc/.HOME}
>   D/dalvikvm(  406): GC_EXPLICIT freed 418 objects / 26008 bytes in 90ms
>   I/Process (13612): Sending signal. PID: 13612 SIG: 9
>   I/ActivityManager(  240): Process jano.huerta.sfgc (pid 13612) has
>   died. I/WindowManager(  240): WIN DEATH: Window{466cb800
>   jano.huerta.sfgc/jano.huerta. sfgc.SFGC paused=true}
>   W/ActivityManager(  240): Activity destroy timeout for
>   HistoryRecord{46654450 ja no.huerta.sfgc/.SFGC}

Comment: give us the details of the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common mistake here is forgetting to register the 'That' activity in your AndroidManifest.xml. Have you done that?

Also, it would be much easier to help you if you pasted the stack trace from your crash. You can see crash info, amongst other logging, by running `adb logcat`.

Comment: I have registered the "THAT" activity with the same intent-filter as "Something" but still crashes. Unsure how to get a stack trace. I have the debugger running in Eclipse but I'm still figuring out how to make any sense of it.

Edit: I think I figure out the stack trace, will edit question.

Comment: That stacktrace looks incomplete as I don't see anything that looks like your code in there. Normally in the log, you see a stacktrace like that one followed by a smaller stacktrace that is mostly limited to your code. This only tells half of the story. Not sure if this is eclipse's fault or yours, but adb logcat really is the simplest way.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if it was possible to send the logcat command within Eclipse so I opened a cmd shell and took the log from there. I hope it came out properly and I can see that it does have code related to mine. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Alejandro, Which is the SUMMARY Activity? Did u change it here for our benefit?

Comment: Well... I figured out what the problem was. I was exactly what you mentioned earlier with the Manifest. I forgot to add the Summary activity for the tabHost. Ah I feel... slow lol. Thank you very much, the logcat helped me figure it out and now I know better. Thanks again.

@st0le no thats an actual activity with a tabHost I am using, but apparently I forgot to add that one. The problem has been fixed =D

Answer (score 0):

## Never forget to add the `<activity>` tag in the Manifest.xml.

All activities **MUST** be added in the Manifest File. Android Activity is an essential Android Component which should be registered.

#### Why?

The Activity is started and destroyed by Android OS. So when you call,

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
startActicvity(i);
```

Then the OS looks for the Activity in the `Manifest.xml` file. If it does not find the matching activity then you will get following error:

> android.content.ActivityNot FoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity

#### How to add activity in Manifest file?

Add this in the Manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".TargetActivity"/>
```

It is the most basic form. You can explore more [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#components)